# Which device is displayed on line 2 of the tracert output

Tags: ip, traceroute

Running a tracert produced the following output below.

```
1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  WRT610N [192.168.1.1]  0/ 100 =  0%   |

2  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  10.88.192.1  0/ 100 =  0%   |

3   16ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  d226-4-141.home.cgocable.net [24.226.4.141]
```

My question is what device has the IP address 10.88.192.1? The router is 192.168.1.1 and the ISP is cogeco cable which explains the 3rd line, what  has the private IP address on line 2 (10.88.192.1)? Is it the cable modem? 
There is a hardware firewall but the management interface is on a different network. It does not respond to pings or  port 80.

Comment: And you think this is programming related how exactly?

Comment: This is not a programming question and is off-topic here. The router is 192.168.1.1 on the *inside* of your network (the side you see). It's probably 10.88.192.1 on the other side (the part those outside of your network can see) of the same router.

Comment: That is the first hop past your router, so it is whatever is immediately upstream from you, so it is part of your ISP's network. Is your cable modem IP'd? Maybe it is a core router? Since it is immediately upstream, you can get a pcap of traffic to it and get the MAC and then run it through this: http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/

Comment: I suspect your "cable modem" is actually a router as well.

Answer (score 0):

That IP is most likely the Cable/Bundle interface on the CMTS. Cable modem is a bridge* between ethernet and RF network and it will not appear in traceroute so the first hop (if you dont have any routers in your local network) is a CMTS.

*It is also an IP node so it does have an IP address but in order to communicate with it the traffic **must** pass through CMTS. (This of course does not apply for the local IP address of the modem, usually from `192.168.x.x` subnet).